# Metasploit Handler doesnt show options

Tags: metasploit

I am trying to use `exploit/multi/handler` module which I have used before and it does not allow me to set options. The options commands displays nothing. I tried reinstalling (`apt-get remove metasploit-framework && apt-get install metasploit-framework`) but nothing changed.

I am running msfconsole on Kali Linux

Comment: When needing help on a command, it is very helpful to post the actual command you ran and what actually happens. It helps prevent a lot of back and forth questions. Copy/paste the text and use the code formatting tool.

Comment: The question I have is, did you run `options` or `show options`?

Comment: @schroeder aren't those equivalent commands nowadays? Also, you will not see any options unless you select a payload.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you select a payload (e.g. `set payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp`), there are no options to set since the multi handler does not have unique functionality of its own.